# Heroku login - JSONError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ' '

Tags: heroku, terminal, vagrant

I am trying to login to my Heroku account in my terminal. But, when I type `heroku login`, a message appears saying press a key to open up my browser but the browser does not open and the login fails then, this message appears.

```
JSONError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ' '
at module.exports (/usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/parse-json/index.js:26:19)
at HTTP._parse (/usr/lib/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-auth/node_modules/http-call/lib/http.js:343:25)
```

Note that, I am using virtual machine vagrant if it is important !. Also, I am using Ubuntu OS.

[image]

Update: I tired to login without using a virtual machine and I successfully logged in So, I suspect Vagrant is the problem !.

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution to this problem
Along with the heroku login use --interactive flag.

`heroku login --interactive`

[here is the link where you can read about it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1530)